React-Native undefined browser tab titles? react-router-dom Navigate
We are getting an issue using react-native where when we navigate to another page using the react-router-dom, it sends you to the correct page, but the tab title displays undefined. Once you refresh the page, however, it displays the correct screen title. Here is an example of where we navigate to the /login page:
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { getItem } from "../utils/localStorageUtil";
import WebMain from "./WebMain";
import { HomeStack } from "./WebMain";

const AuthContainer = () => {

  const token = getItem('token');

  return token ? <WebMain stack={HomeStack} /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />
}

export default AuthContainer;

Here is what our routes look like:
import * as React from 'react';
import MobileMain from './navigation/MobileMain';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import ViewPage from './Components/ViewOnlyComponents/ViewPage';
import WebMain, { GalleryStack, LibraryStack, ProfileStack, LoginStack, RegisterStack, VerificationStack, CameraConnectionsStack } from './navigation/WebMain';
import { MenuProvider } from 'react-native-popup-menu';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { DataProvider } from './Components/ContextProvider';
import AuthContainer from './navigation/AuthContainer';

const PageNotFound = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
    <p>Oops! The page you're looking for does not exist.</p>
  </div>
);

const PathRouter = () => (
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      {/* Route with URL parameters */}
      <Route path="/view-photos/:parameter1/" element={<ViewPage />} />
      {/* Route for when "/view" parameter is not present */}
      <Route path="/" element={<AuthContainer />} />
      <Route path="/home" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<WebMain stack={LoginStack} />} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<WebMain stack={RegisterStack} />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
);

Here's what the LoginStack looks like:
export const LoginStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

So the tab should display the name "Login". When we redirect, or even copy links to other pages, it initially sets the tab title as undefined. Once you refresh, it puts the correct name there. Any insight as to why and how we can fix this?
Expected to redirect to a page using Navigate or useNavigate from the dom package, and have it display the tab name correctly. It initally doesn't on the redirect and only displays undefined. After a refresh of the browser page, it displays the correct name

Why are you using React-Navigation and React-Router-DOM at the same time? I highly recommend you switch to using only one of these routing and navigation libraries. Try reducing the complexity and see if using one or the other helps address the problem.

Interesting problem, seems like a delay or lack of update when switching to the page. Have you tried leveraging the title property of the Stack component?
    export const LoginStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} title="Login" />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

You can find more on it here

this didn't seem to solve the undefined issue, but good to know that exists
